# SQL syntax using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I'm trying to insert values into some table with this code using C# and SQL:

```
string query1 = "select PlayerID from Table1";
string query2 = "select GameID from Table2";

string q = "insert into Table3 (PlayerID, GameID) values(" + query1 + "," + query2 + ")";
```

Is it possible?

**Edit:**

I have 3 tables:

1. `playersTbl` - with auto increment id (primary key)
2. `gameTbl`  - with auto increment id (primary key)
3. `JoinTbl`

When the game is starting, the user can register some players to the same game, so
in the same game lets say there are 4 players.

When I'm adding those 4 players the `playersTbl` will look like:

```
ID | first name|
----------------
1  | p1        |
2  | p2        |
3  | p3        |
4  | p4        |
```

and the `gameTbl` will look like:

```
ID | Date | Hour|
-----------------
1  |      |     |
```

So what I'm trying to do is the `Table3` will look like:

```
PlayerID | GameID|
------------------
1        | 1     |
2        | 1     |
3        | 1     |
4        | 1     |
```

Now when I'm starting a new game with one player

I'm adding the player to the `playersTbl`, and the game to the `gameTbl`, but now the third table will look like

```
 PlayerID | GameID|
    ------------------
    1        | 1     |
    2        | 1     |
    3        | 1     |
    4        | 1     |
    5        | 2     |
```

**to be more clear, I don't want that players which are registered in the second game will be in the first game..**

Comment: Avoid concatenating strings into SQL - this can open you to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 2):

use `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO Table3(PlayerID, GameID)
SELECT  a.PlayerID, b.GameID
FROM    Table1 a CROSS JOIN Table2 b
```

what the query does is it produces cartesian product from both tables.

Consider The following example,

Table1

```
PlayerID
========
1
2
3
```

Table2

```
GameID
=======
10
11
12
```

when the query below is executed,

```
SELECT  a.PlayerID, b.GameID
FROM    Table1 a CROSS JOIN Table2 b
```

it produces the following result,

```
PlayerID    GameID
=========   ======
1           10
1           11
1           12
2           10
2           11
2           12
3           10
3           11
3           12
```

Comment: yeah but i'm trying not to make a cartesian product.. i'll edited my question so you can understand what i'm trying to do, but anyway thanks for the question

Comment: @Elior please do. Looking at your queries, it fetches all ID from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to utilize the INSERT INTO SELECT method, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (PlayerID, GameID) SELECT Table1.ID, Table2.ID FROM Table1, Table2
```